TV Episode about a boy who can summon things he sees in a picture or book
My vague recollections of this episode are of a grandfather type of person taking care of a boy with special needs. (I am 99% confident the grandfather was played by George Gaynes, though his IMDB/Wikipedia pages don't hint at an episode or even story-within-a-movie that resembles this.)
This boy would huddle and roll backwards-and-forwards and say "BRING!!!" when he focussed on a picture or photo in a book and he would magically bring those things/objects into his hands.   I think a Child Services worker was investigating why this boy was being sheltered and protected at home and came in to interview the grandfather. I also recall that the boy ended up summoning terrible things (after reading a book on anatomy) that led to his grandmother dying of a heart-attack after walking into the room filled with bloody human body parts ... which is why his grandfather never ever wanted him to go outside or see pictures because he could hurt more people.
The episode ended with the Grandfather wanting to end it all and showing the boy a book making him focus on a page with a picture of an inferno/fire/explosion ... which the boy summoned and in the process engulfed them both.
I think this was made in the 80s. Very Twilight-zone-ish.

It's Richard Mulligan, not George Gaynes, although they do look alike. This is The Toys of Caliban from the second season of the New Twilight Zone. I'd post a recap, but you've already described it perfectly. Here's the teaser:




nailed it. Loved this when I was a kid. :)

You recall perhaps a reboot of an old sci-fi story (kornbluth?) Adapted by Sterling and starring Billy Mummy in the early series (1960?) And re-adapted the movie. Along with some other episodes.
After the kid spun the community into its own dimension, everyone had to think happy thoughts or the kid would think one into a cornfield.

You're referring to It's a Good Life,  which is a reminiscent story but ultimately not the same. A different answer has already been approved.

Yes, I am aware of that other "misunderstood kid with powers" episode (including the equally awesome Johnny Bravo parody of it many years later)
